# mod_rewrite rule for wildcard subdomains?

Tags: mod-rewrite

Sorry if this has been covered, I can't find anything on this specifically.

I have wildcard subdomains on (*.mysite.com) I need a mod_rewrite expression for this rewrite:

bob.mysite.com => mysite.com/users/index.php?user=bob

bob.mysite.com/profile/ => mysite.com/users/index.php?user=bob/profile/

Obviously "bob" and "profile" are just examples, I need the general case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $ operator will let you extract backreferences from matches in rewrite rules and the % operator will let you extract references from conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mysite.com$ [NC] # Presuming you don't want to do www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com [NC] # Catch subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC] # Don't rewrite if we already have
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/index.php?user=%1$1 [L]
```

Comment: this almost works, except the $1 backreference returns the new address /users/index.php instead of the requested /profile/. Can you help?

Comment: hmm... yeah, it will be rewriting it twice. Try with the edit included above.