# Redirect/rewrite dynamic URL to sub-domain and create DNS for subdomain

Tags: htaccess, redirects, dns, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have created an application in PHP, I would like to re-direct the following URL to corresponding sub-domain.

Dynamic URL pattern:

```
http://mydomain.com/mypage.php?user_name=testuser
```

I wish to re-direct this to the corresponding sub domain:

```
http://testuser.mydomain.com/
```

1. How do I create a rewrite rule for this purpose?
2. How do I register DNS for sub-domain **without** using CPANEL? (I want to
   activate sub-domain when the user registers to the system.)

Comment: Are you sure you want to have **subdomain testuser** with host www in it, not *host testuser*  in base domain?

Comment: [@Lazy Badge](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/10489/lazy-badger)mydomain is the main domain and testuser is the sudomain.

Comment: for which task you want to give **domain** to user? It's possible, just can't see reasons

Comment: I want  to give  personalized site for each user.They can edit their page.

Comment: "site" is **host**, **not domain**. Learn **correct** terms! www isn't mandatory in site-name - it's same hostname, as others - you just make sitename unnesessary long and complex

Comment: If you mean you want the sub-domain activated automatically when the user registers, you might be going about this a bit wrong(or at least inefficiently). Instead, enable [wildcard sub-domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record). Then see [this previous question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14048/mod-rewrite-rule-for-wildcard-subdomains). (If that does work for your situation, be sure to come back and request this be closed as a duplicate, or just trash it yourself.)

Comment: What you need is right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Answer (score 3):

[Take a look at this thread over at webmaster world](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/368.htm)

You'll need to create:-

- A DNS mapping: `*.yourdomain.com => your IP`
- A server alias `*.yourdomain.com` in your virtualhost configuration

.htaccess file with something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond &#37;{HTTP_HOST} ^user\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user [R=301,L]
```

You can replace `user` with `([a-z])` and use it in the `rewriteRule`. That way you can have a general mapping: `something.yourdomain.com => yourdomain.com/user`, even if the user isn't signed up to your site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a wildcard DNS rule for the subdomains, then you can do a rewrite rule to redirect that link to the correct domain.

Information on this can be found here: http://www.thecpaneladmin.com/setting-up-wildcard-dns-with-cpanel/

You will need access to the configuration files so it may not be easy depending on your host and hosting plan.